# How to allow outgoing request from gcp cloud functions with node 16?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloud

I am using node 16 with cloud functions. and I am using Twilio and outlook APIs.
I can access this third party apis in my local system using `firebase function serve`,

but when I deploy this functions on GCP, all outgoing request like accessing third party APIs not working and gives error related,

Connection timed out and code: 'ECONNABORTED'.

So how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to allow outgoing requests from Google Cloud Functions with Node.js version 16, you need to configure the environment variable `'FUNCTIONTRIGGERTYPE' to 'http'`.

This can be done by adding the following to the cloud function's configuration file:

```
environment_variables:
  FUNCTION_TRIGGER_TYPE: http
```

Once the environment variable has been set, you can then use the http module to make outgoing requests from inside your cloud function.
For example:

```
const http = require('http');

exports.myFunction = (req, res) => {
  const options = {
    hostname: 'example.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET'
  };
  const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
    // handle response
  });
  req.end();
};
```

Additionally,  check below points also :

- you should make sure that the network access control lists of your
  VPC allow the outbound requests from the cloud function. You can do
  this by adding an egress rule to the VPC.
- You can also use the Node.js http or https modules to make requests.
  You can find more information about making requests with Node.js in
  the [Node.js documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/nodejs-runtime#console)

Comment: I am using the cloud functions as a http request and I am using axios, so no need to set environment variable.

Your second suggestion to add egress rule in VPC, that is the way for my solution. but in my case, after adding the egress rule in VPC, is did not work, then I set the `vpcConnectorEgressSettings` setting to `PRIVATE_RANGES_ONLY` and it works.

so basically all private request pass through VPC and all public request avoid the VPC and we can directly access the target resources using public APIs.